# Oracle SQL Developer ORA-00904 on alter table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, alter, notnull

I'm currently trying to alter an existing Oracle SQL table in Oracle SQL Developer.

I want to add a field to an existing table.
The field should be not null, type NVARCHAR(256) and store a simple string - no foreign keys needed.

My SQL looks like this:

```
alter table MYTABLE
add column FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256) not null default 'apple';
```

When I run this sql statement, I get the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
alter table MYTABLE
add column FRUITS  NVARCHAR2(256) not null default 'apple'
Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Do you know how to solve this error?

Comment: This is a syntax error. You can find the answers for such questions in the Oracle documentation. It is online, comprehensive and free. You should [bookmark it for future reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/).

Comment: Some commands - and ALTER TABLE is one - have a bewildering array of possibilities, but there are examples which cover most things. If you have compared the [SQL guide examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877) with your code you could have solved this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax as well as wrong order of constraints.

Should be

```
alter table MYTABLE
add FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256) default 'apple' not null;
```

---

Demonstration:

```
SQL> create table mytable (id number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table MYTABLE
  2  add column FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256) not null default 'apple';
add column FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256) not null default 'apple'
    *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL> alter table MYTABLE
  2  add FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256) not null default 'apple';
add FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256) not null default 'apple'
                                           *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-30649: missing DIRECTORY keyword


SQL> alter table MYTABLE
  2  add FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256) default 'apple' not null;

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is now right. Remove **column** after add and place **not null** after 'apple'

```
alter table MYTABLE
add  FRUITS NVARCHAR2(256)  default 'apple' not null;
```